# Remove a form field from an embedded symfony 5 form

Tags: php, symfony

I have a symfony 5 form with 2 fields on it: a state field and a city field. On the form a user must select a State but the City field is not required. If I submit the form with both a State and a City it works perfect. The issue is when I try to save the form with only a State selected that I get an error on submission even though City is not required. After some xdebugging I figured out that the issue of course is that the form wants there to be a city.

It's also not a SQL issue because the field is `nullable` in the Database.

I am using Symfony form events in an attempt to just remove the form the City field if it is empty or has no data but It does not seem to have any effect and I still get the initial error message.

Is there something missing from the code?

I tried this:

```
  $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
        function(FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();

            if (!$form->getData()) {
                //remove this field from the form if there is no city entered
                $form->remove('city');
            }
        });
```

and this:

```
  $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
        function(FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();

            if (!$form->getData()) {
                //remove this field from the form if there is no location entered
                $form->getParent()->remove('city'); //difference is here
            }
        });
```

Error thrown because the city field is empty

```
ErrorException
array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values!
```

Comment: If the field is not required, then you shouldn't need to go through any gymnastics to deal with an empty value. You might show your entity annotations for the field. Also, you should show the actual error.

Comment: have you set city as `'required' => false` when creating the form?
i.e. if using a FormType
`$builder  ->add('state', TextType::class, array('label' => '')) ->add('city', TextType::class, array('label' => '', 'empty_data'=>'', 'required' => false));`

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. My solution was to instead pass in an empty array on `PRE_SUBMIT` if `city` field was empty.

```
$data = $form->getData();

if (empty($data['city']) {
        $data['city']= [];
        $event->setData($data);
    }
```